# AutoBeanCodex.encode leaves out properties with default values

Tags: gwt, autobean

I'm comunicating with a web service via `AutoBean`s that are converted to JSON. The problem is that the web service expects every property of the JSON object to be present in the request whereas `AutoBeanCodex.encode()` seemingly leaves out all properties that have their default values (despite those being set explicitly).

Is there a way to include those properties too?

**EDIT:** Thomas' answer already helped a lot, but it still leaves a little problem. Namely an empty array (`List<Integer>` in my case) is swallowed as well, apparently because the default value there would be the empty array and not `null`.

Answer (score 5):

A workaround would probably be to use the wrapper types instead of the primitive ones, e.g. `Boolean` instead of `boolean`, `Integer` instead of `int`; that way, the *default value* would be `null` rather than `false` or `0`.

Comment: Thanks, in a way this should have been an obvious workaround. While I was busy thinking of ways to change that behaviour or even find the tiniest bit of documentation about it.

Comment: One minor problem remains, in that `List<Integer>` will result in a left-out property too instead of an empty array. Any hint on that one?

Comment: Has anyone figured out a solution? I am having a similar issue with Date. I need json to have null for my date value. Thanks